# Probabilistic record linkage (matching) in PostgreSQL and Python

Tags: python, postgresql, match

I am trying to match records from two tables without a common key and with some errors in the data. Specifically I have records in Table A for a given group and date that I want to match with records in Table B with the same group, but the date may differ. Additionally some records may only exist in table A or B.

**Example tables**

```
Table A
=========================
id | group |   date | ...
---+-------+--------+----
 0 |     A | 1/1/15 | ...
 1 |     B | 1/3/15 | ...
 2 |     A | 1/5/15 | ...
 3 |     A | 1/5/15 | ...
 : |     : |      : | :::
99 |     Z | 4/5/15 | ...

Table B
=========================
id | group |   date | ...
---+-------+--------+----
 0 |     A | 1/2/15 | ...
 1 |     A | 1/5/15 | ...
 2 |     A | 1/6/15 | ...
 : |     : |      : | :::
99 |     Z | 4/5/15 | ...
```

Here I would want record 0 in table A to match with record 0 in table B even though the dates are different (but are close), record 1 in table A is missing in table B, and there may be multiple records in table A (or B) with the same group and date (these are not duplicates).

Currently I am not matching records where the dates differ, but I am losing potentially useful data. Therefore I would like to iteratively improve the matching so that I have more complete matching. I think that a probabilistic approach would make the most sense rather than a deterministic one, but am open to arguments on this.

My first question is what the right tool for this is. Currently the tables are in a PostgresSQL database and are large enough that it would be difficult to process them on a local machine. However I am not familiar with any way of performing probabilistic joins in Postgres, but I expect that Python has good (enough) support for probabilistic record linkage.

Can (should) this be done in Postgres or a different tool (Python)? Can anyone direct me to any resources (examples, code, etc.)?

Comment: how many rows are we talking? how much ram do you have?

Comment: 300,000+ rows with about a dozen columns of interest in each table. 16GB ram

Answer (score -1):

I have used pg_trgm (tri grams) extensively and developed an elemental weight hierarchy (scoring and weight factors on each combination or single element matches). The Trigrams put the 'records' together if you join by the trigram and then evaluate the scores as a sorting mechanism.

Also, be sure you 'standardize' your data first before matching.

PostGIS is useful for addresses, and general x-walk for gender 
Formatting on phones, emails, etc.

> sel * from LIFE;